# What is the correct way to use linq type methods with IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, iasyncenumerable

There does not seem to be any included linq support for IAsyncEnumerable packaged with .NET Core. What is the correct way to be able to do simple things such as ToList and Count?

Comment: If you're just going to call ToList or Count - then what's the point of using an async enumerator method?

Comment: Why is this closed? It's a good and clear question.

Comment: Please vote to reopen this the question does make perfect sense and as you can see it has straightforward answer

Comment: Thanks @Stilgar, I didn't know that was a thing 

Comment: [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) Nuget package.

Comment: @stuartd how I use the enumerable and how I consume it are two different things. You can certainly have a situation where you need all of the data in an async enumerable to work with, hence ToList(), and others where you only need to process them as they become available

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a good question, as there are next to no useful items in IntelliSense on `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` out of the box with the implicit framework reference you'd have with a default .NET Core app.

It is expected that you would add the `System.Linq.Async` (know as Ix Async, [see here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive#systemlinqasync--systeminteractiveasync--systeminteractive)) package like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Async" Version="4.0.0" />
```

Then you can use `CountAsync`, or `ToListAsync`:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    yield return 1;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    yield return 2;
}

var count = await Numbers().CountAsync();
var myList = await Numbers().ToListAsync();
```

As pointed out in a comment, these methods aren't that useful on their own, they should be used after you have used the more powerful features while keeping your data as an asynchronous stream, with things like `SelectAwait` and `WhereAwait` etc...

Comment: The methods do have uses as it is. What if I am handed an API that is IAsyncEnumerable but I don't really care about the asyncness of it? Should I be forced to foreach-count myself (which is probably what CountAsync does anyway)?

Comment: You have to care about the asyncness of it, you can't opt out, it's the same as an `async` method. Don't block on it, unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: But CountAsync isn't blocking. You are just awaiting the full sequence. If you await-foreach and then count in a variable it would have the same effect.

Comment: Yes it would, I don't think I understood your first comment then